# summation for $x \gt 1$

Tags: summation, geometric-series

how do I show that the $\sum_{n=0}^{n=N} (n+1)x^n$ is less than or equal to the **square** of this whole sum : $\sum_{n=0}^{n=N}x^n$

Tried induction didn't work. Got messy

tried doing directly by using the formula to a  geometric series- didn't work

Would really appreciate some help

Thanks

Comment: Induction won't work here because $x\in \mathbb{R}$ see [description on wikipedia page of mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)

Comment: but this is induction on N?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Both sums can be done in closed form. One is a geometric series, the other is the derivative of a geometric series.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{array}\\
\displaystyle\left(\sum_{n=0}^N x^n\right)^2
&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{m=0}^N x^{n+m}\\
&\ge\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{m=0}^{N-n} x^{n+m}\\
&=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^N x^j \sum_{m=0}^{j} 1
\quad (j=n+m)\\
&=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^N (j+1)x^j\\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the close form sums of this two sequences. The difference is something positive.